# Why does a specific method have to be located at a specific location inside of JavaScript and cannot be moved around?

Tags: javascript, html

My question is why does drawScreen have to be located where it is and cannot be moved outside of the method. It is like a method inside a method. I think that this is where I am still weak on JavaScript because there seems times when method, like this one, should be able to be moved outside of where it is as long as it can be called from some point inside of the script.

**Question: Why does the drawScreen() method have to be located where it is in the code?**

Code Here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chapter 1 Example 6 Canvas Sub Dom Example </title>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);  

var Debugger = function () { };
Debugger.log = function (message) {
    try {
        console.log(message);
    } catch (exception) {
        return;
    }
}


function eventWindowLoaded () {
    canvasApp();
}

function canvasSupport () {
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}



function canvasApp () {

        if (!canvasSupport()) {
             return;
        }

        var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
        var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d"); 

        Debugger.log("Drawing Canvas");


        **function drawScreen() {
            //background
            context.fillStyle = "#ffffaa";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);

            //text
            context.fillStyle    = "#000000";
            context.font         = "20px Sans-Serif";
            context.textBaseline = "top";
            context.fillText  ("Hello World!", 195, 80 );

            //image
            var helloWorldImage = new Image();

            helloWorldImage.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(helloWorldImage, 155, 110);
            }
            helloWorldImage.src = "helloworld.gif";
            //box

            context.strokeStyle = "#000000"; 
            context.strokeRect(5,  5, 490, 290);

        }**

        drawScreen();
}


</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="300">
 <div>A yellow background with an image and text on top
     <ol>
        <li>The text says "Hello World"</li>
        <li>The image is of the planet earth.</li>
        </ol>
   </div>
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: What variables does `drawScreen()` access, and where are those variables declared?

Comment: They are declared inside so I would have to pass the variables to the out side method but it would work then, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has lexical scope, so it inherits the scope of outer functions (scope is dependant on where functions are located in source code).

In order to move it out, you'd need to either pass it the data it needs (`context`) or make it available via some other means.